Windows Exporer directory context menu with "Find with Notepad+++"
Notepad++ has a "Find in Files" functionality where one is able to find some string in particular files or all files in selected folder. I'd like to have a Windows Explorer folder/directory context menu (right click on a folder/directory) like "Find with Notepad++" where when I click on it the Notepad++ opens with Find in Files with this folder/directory already selected.
Is it possible to create such a context menu?

Have you checked if Notepad++ supports controlling its find feature? From the command line perhaps?

Yes, I checked but did not find solution and that's why I ask here.
